# MailDefinition's CreateMailMessage owner from ASP.Net MVC Controller

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, email

What do I send as the owner for a MailDefinition.CreateMailMessage() sent through an ASP.Net MVC Controller?

```
//   owner:
//     The System.Web.UI.Control that owns this System.Web.UI.WebControls.MailDefinition.
public MailMessage CreateMailMessage(string recipients, IDictionary replacements, Control owner);
```

Edit:  sending a new System.Web.UI.Control() seems to work ok.  Is there a different/standard solution?

Comment: You're goign to need to provide a lot more detail. What exactly are you trying to accomplish? We can't read your mind

Comment: sending a new System.Web.UI.Control() works fine, please close this question.  thanks

Answer (score 9):

I had the same problem as Adam after adapting the code described in [system.web.ui.webcontrols.maildefinition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.maildefinition.aspx)

The solution is to replace "this" by "new System.Web.UI.Control()"

For example, in the C# Microsoft example above, instead of:

```
fileMsg = md.CreateMailMessage(sourceTo.Text, replacements, this);
```

In an MVC Controller you would write:

```
fileMsg = mailDefinition.CreateMailMessage("email@address.com", replacements, new System.Web.UI.Control());
```